# Database query to get the most recently updated entity

Tags: mysql, database, join, relationship

I have two tables in MySQL database-

```
/* main theatre table */
CREATE TABLE THEATRE 
(
id VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
location VARCHAR(100),
type VARCHAR(100), /* comma separated values */ 
createDateTime BIGINT NOT NULL /* Current time in milliseconds everytime a record is inserted */
);


/* table to capture all theatre activity */
CREATE TABLE THEATRE_ACTIVITY
(
id VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
theatreId VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL REFERENCES THEATRE(id),
activity VARCHAR(20), /* (RATED | CREATED | EDITED) */
createDateTime BIGINT NOT NULL /* Current time in milliseconds everytime a record is inserted */
);
```

Every time there is an activity in a `THEATRE` a record is inserted in T`HEATRE_ACTIVITY` table. I need to get all (`distinct`) names, ids and locations of all `THEATRE`s based on `THEATRE_ACTIVITY` `createDateTime`, from most recent to last.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, location
from theatre  INNER JOIN 
(select theatreid, MAX(createDateTime)
from theatre_activity
group by theatreId) ta ON theatre.id = ta.theatreId
```

The query will fetch all the distinct theatres (assuming there are no duplicates in theatre table) which have theatre activities.
If there are more than one activity, then most recent is selected. This is what I understood from your problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @Zohaib, however, I am getting the same error for your query as I am from Naveen's - unknown column 'ta.theatreid' in 'on clause'. Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a query, what i understood from your problem statement.

```
select DISTINCT t.id, t.name, t.location from theatre t, theatre_activity ta where t.id = ta.theatreId order by t.id desc
```

Comment: Thanks @Kandarp. This is not working. Actually, I am trying to get a list of all theatres based on decreasing order of their activity - from most to least. And because the activity is stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select id, name, location, ta.td
from theatre  INNER JOIN 
(select theatreid, MAX(createDateTime) td
from theatre_activity
group by theatreId  ) ta ON theatre.id = ta.theatreId  order by ta.td desc
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, however, the query is giving me following error - unknown column 'ta.theatreid' in 'on clause'. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: Does this query work for you `select theatreid, MAX(createDateTime) td
from theatre_activity group by theatreId` ?